# Interpreting Visual Studio Code extension host exceptions in compressed java script

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, exception

I'm writing a Visual Studio Code extension and ran into problems interpreting exception stacktraces. These are raised from compressed java script code within VSCode and although I do have access to the source code repository in principle, I cannot find the matching typescript line to analyse what is happening. Example:

```
[2022-02-01 07:53:28.112] [renderer5] [error] Cannot read property 'length' of undefined: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at c:\prj\VSCode-1.61.2\data\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655\out\client\extension.js:67:257359
    at p (c:\prj\VSCode-1.61.2\data\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655\out\client\extension.js:67:262355)
    at U.provideCompletionItems (c:\gom\VSCode-1.61.2\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:180703)
```

So I probably set up some object in a wrong way and the 'length' property is missing. But I have no chance finding the line of code which tries to access it to get a hint which object.

Is there a way to find the matching uncompressed typescript line with the information in that stacktrace ?

Comment: What are you using to bundle/minify your extension? Can it produce a source map?

Comment: what is `ms-python` doing on the stacktrace

Comment: I'm not minifying the extension code. The stacktrace originates from the VSCode installation and I would like to evaluate what went wrong in the depths of the VSCode code, which is already rolled out minified.

Comment: The stacktrace posting above is just an example. ms-python is involved here because that particular problem arose when adding completion items for a python editor, but the problem is the same for all other kinds of errors from different modules.